# Haskell (Title along with users ratings)

Tags: haskell

this is a project of a film database. I have to display the title of the film and the user's rating.

With this code I'm able to display all the films that the user's has rated (along with the other users ratings).

```
-- Types
type Title = String
type Director = String
type Year = Int
type Mark = Int
type Rating = (String, Int)

-- Define Film type here
type Film = (Title, Director, Year, [Rating])

-- Define database type here
type Database = [Film]

testDatabase :: [Film]
testDatabase =
  [("Casino Royale", "Martin Campbell",  2006, [("Garry",8),("Dave", 0)])
  ,("Blade Runner",  "Ridley Scott",     1982, [("Amy",  5),("Dave", 9)])
  ,("The Fly",       "David Cronenberg", 1986, [("Fred", 7),("Dave", 4)])
  ]

hasRated :: [Rating] -> String -> Bool
hasRated [] givenUsername = False
hasRated ((name, rate):xs) givenUsername
            | name == givenUsername && rate > 0 = True
            | otherwise = hasRated xs givenUsername 

listRatedFilms :: String -> Film -> Bool
listRatedFilms givenUsername (t, d, y, r) = hasRated r givenUsername

displayFilmsRating :: String -> Database -> String
displayFilmsRating username database = 
  displayRatedFilm (filter (listRatedFilms username) database)

displayRatedFilm :: Database -> String
displayRatedFilm database = concat(map displayRatedFilms database)

displayRatedFilms :: Film -> String
displayRatedFilms (title, director, year, rating) = 
  "\nTitle: " ++ title ++ "\nRating: " ++ (show rating) ++ "\n"
```

How is possible to get the rating of the user of each movie separated.

Current unwanted result:

```
ghci> displayFilmsRating "Zoe" testDatabase

Title: Hugo
Rating: [("Sam",4),("Wally",3),("Zoe",4),("Liz",7)]

Title: Vertigo
Rating: [("Bill",7),("Emma",5),("Zoe",9),("Olga",6),("Tim",10)]

Title: Lincoln
Rating: [("Ian",3),("Sam",7),("Wally",3),("Zoe",4),("Liz",7),("Megan",4)]
```

Wanted reuslt:

> Title: Titanic
>   Rating: 7
>
> Title: Avatar
>   Rating: 7

All other Users Rating should be gone somehow!

**Update:**

I made another attempt but no luck. You might take a look and give some idea if you like:

```
listRatedFilms :: String -> Film -> Bool
listRatedFilms givenUsername (t, d, y, r) = hasRated r givenUsername

hasRated :: [Rating] -> String -> Bool
hasRated [] givenUsername = False
hasRated ((name, rate):xs) givenUsername
            | name == givenUsername && rate > 0 = True
            | otherwise = hasRated xs givenUsername 

-- This new function returns a database, whith all the films that the user has rated
findLikedFilms :: String -> Database -> Database
findLikedFilms username database = filter (listRatedFilms username) database

-- these functions returns the rating of the user's
takeMark :: [Rating] -> String -> Int
takeMark [] givenUsername = 0
takeMark ((name, rate):xs) givenUsername
            | name == givenUsername && rate > 0 = rate
            | otherwise = takeMark xs givenUsername 

takeMarks :: String -> Film -> Int
takeMarks givenUsername (t, d, y, r) = takeMark r givenUsername 
--

displayFilmsRating :: String -> Database -> String
displayFilmsRating username database = map (findLikedFilms (username database)) (takeMarks (username database))

displayRatedFilms :: Database -> Int -> String
displayRatedFilms database mark = concat(map (displayRatedFilmtest database) mark)

displayRatedFilmtest :: Film -> Int -> String
displayRatedFilmtest (title, director, year, rating) mark = "\nTitle: " ++ title ++ "\nRating: " ++ (show mark) ++ "\n"
```

Somehow I have to write the functions displayFilmsRating and displayRatedFilms in a way that puts everything together and returns to the displayRatedFilmtest function the film and the mark.

With these functions I'm able to get the results I need separately but I've no luck to put them together in a function.

**Last Edit:**
I trying to display the results of displayRatedFilmsForUser through the displayRatedFilm functions but when I change the output of displayRatedFilmsForUser from IO() to string getting an error and its asking for IO(). when its IO() its working fine.
Whats going wrong with my modification?

```
displayRatedFilmsForUser :: String -> Database -> IO()
displayRatedFilmsForUser username database = mapM_ (showResult) $ findLikedFilms username database
  where
    showResult film@(t, _, _, rs) = displayRatedFilm t (takeMarks username film)

displayRatedFilm :: Title -> Mark -> String
displayRatedFilm title mark = "\nTitle: " ++ (show title) ++ "\nRating: " ++ (show mark) ++ "\n"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import Data.List (nub, sort)

-- Types
type Title = String
type Director = String
type Year = Int
type Mark = Int
type Rating = (String, Int)

-- Define Film type here
type Film = (Title, Director, Year, [Rating])

-- Define database type here
type Database = [Film]

testDatabase :: [Film]
testDatabase =
  [("Casino Royale", "Martin Campbell",  2006, [("Garry",8),("Dave", 0)])
  ,("Blade Runner",  "Ridley Scott",     1982, [("Amy",  5),("Dave", 9)])
  ,("The Fly",       "David Cronenberg", 1986, [("Fred", 7),("Dave", 4)])
]

-- used to be called listRatedFilms, but this does not make a list of Films
hasUserRatedFilm :: String -> Film -> Bool
hasUserRatedFilm givenUsername (_, _, _, r) = hasRating r givenUsername

-- was hasRated
hasRating :: [Rating] -> String -> Bool
hasRating rs username = maybe False (> 0) (lookup username rs)

-- This new function returns a database, whith all the films that the user
-- has rated
findLikedFilms :: String -> Database -> Database
findLikedFilms username database = filter (hasUserRatedFilm username) database

-- Finds ratings for the given user. Returns 0 if none are found
takeMarks :: String -> Film -> Int
takeMarks username (_, _, _, rs) = maybe 0 id (lookup username rs)

displayRatedFilmsForUser :: String -> Database -> IO ()
displayRatedFilmsForUser username database =
  mapM_ (putStrLn . showResult) $ findLikedFilms username database
  where
    showResult film@(t, _, _, rs) = "Title: " ++ t ++ "\n" ++ "Rating: " ++
      show (takeMarks username film) ++ "\n"

-- Bonus function
listUsersWithRatings :: Database -> [String]
listUsersWithRatings = nub . sort . concat . map usersWithRatings
  where
    usersWithRatings :: Film -> [String]
    usersWithRatings (_, _, _, rs) = map fst $ filter (\(n, r) -> r > 0) rs
```

Here is a sample run:

```
ghci> displayRatedFilmsForUser "Garry" testDatabase
Title: Casino Royale
Rating: 8

ghci> displayRatedFilmsForUser "Dave" testDatabase
Title: Blade Runner
Rating: 9

Title: The Fly
Rating: 4
```

Comment: Rather than confuse things by completely rewriting my original answer I took the most recent edit from the OP and made a direct response. Sorry if this is bad form.

Comment: Thank you very much Sean, I'll check it out and I'll let you know soon!

Comment: Thanks Sean checked your code out and its exactly what I was looking for.
I've got another problem when I try to import your code to my program. Could you take a look on the Last edit section on my original question please? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I just figured out. Thanks again Sean, you're a life saver!

Answer (score 2):

The code below separates the code finding the data from the code displaying the data. This way you could send it somewhere else, use a GUI, etc.

```
showFilmUserInfo :: String -> Film -> (String, String)
showFilmUserInfo username (t, _, _, rs) = 
    (("Title: " ++ t), ("Rating: " ++ (getUserRating username rs)))
  where
    getUserRating username rs =
      case lookup username rs of    
        -- your ratings are an "association list" see, Data.List
        Just rating -> show rating
        Nothing     -> "unrated"    
        -- or whatever you want to return here

lookupUsersFilmRatings :: String -> Database -> [(String, String)]
lookupUsersFilmRatings username database =
   map (showFilmUserInfo username) database

displayUsersFilmRatings :: String -> Database -> IO [()]
displayUsersFilmRatings username database = 
   mapM_ (putStrLn . (\(t,r) -> t ++ "\n" ++ r ++ "\n"))
         (lookupUsersFilmRatings username database)
```

Example:

```
ghci> displayUsersFilmRatings "Dave" testDatabase
Title: Casino Royale
Rating: 0
Title: Blade Runner
Rating: 9
Title: Ghost Busters
Rating: unrated
Title: The Fly
Rating: 4
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. I really appreciate your help!
But its not exactly what I was looking for.
The output should be just The title of the film that the user has rated along with the rating. Nothing else.
But no worries, I might get something if I put somehow your code's general idea together with mine :)
Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I updated the above with my output and example usage. If this is not what you wanted could you please update your question or comment here?

Comment: Hey Sean, I commented above your comment with more details and the question as-well. Thanks

Comment: So all mine is missing from your example is an extra newline between the results?

Comment: Yeah there is an extra newline between the results. ("\nTitle: " ++ title ++ "\nRating: " ++ (show rating) ++ "\n")

Comment: @user3207652 if you consider an answer good, you ought to up-vote it. And if there's an answer that was helpful to you, you ought to accept it. That's part of how SO works. :)

Comment: @SeanPerry you can use `mapM_` instead of `mapM`, to get rid of the returned `()` values.

Comment: Hello, Sean's code was really useful, but still not what I was looking for, cause it lists rated and unrated films. I've got to list just the rated films along with the user's ratings. I have updated the question with another attempt of mine. It might be useful. I really appreciate your help guys!